# error when running flask - no module with name '_crypt'

Tags: python, flask

i have a problem running flask. It started fine until I loaded a simple login form.

when running flask via gitbash, I get an error like this

```
flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\crypt.py", line 6, in <module>
    import _crypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_crypt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 234, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\****\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from crypt import methods
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\crypt.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise ImportError("The crypt module is not supported on Windows")
ImportError: The crypt module is not supported on Windows
```

btw, i used windows

Comment: it may need to install some C/C++ library which is not part of Python and you have to download and install it manually. But last error `"The crypt module is not supported on Windows"` suggests that this module can't be used with WIndows and you may have to change system

Comment: I was using bcrypt on windows for months. All of a sudden this morning i'm getting this error. With no changes to anything on the server side... But as of writing this, I found the issue. I was creating a new route, and vscode appended a 'from crypt import methods' to the top of the screen. Just removed it, works normally.

Answer (score 5):

remove this from the top of the file:

```
from crypt import methods
```

it should work again. At least it did for me. VSCode may have autogenerated this for you.

Answer (score 2):

This thing occur most times with auto-import in vs code.

If you inspect your code critically, you'd notice that your vs-code editor has automatically included the line of code `from crypt import methods` above your imports.
Just comment or delete it out and try re-running your app again, you'd be in good shape.